# Is it worth it to detect non-UTF Byte Order Marks (BOM) in practice

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, endianness, byte-order-mark

Strictly speaking, the BOM is supposed to be an endianness indicator (as is the case
with UTF-16 and UTF-32), however, it can be used to indicate the encoding used, as is the 
case with UTF-8 BOM marker (EF BB BF).

Being just a double octet code point, the BOM can be converted to any encoding that 
supports double byte code points, and different encodings  for it can result. 
Some examples are listed in the [BOM Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark):

```
UTF-1          F7 64 4C
UTF-EBCDIC     DD 73 66 73
SCSU           0E FE FF[t 4]
BOCU-1         FB EE 28
GB-18030       84 31 95 33
```

Apart from the UTF-8 BOM (which is common and causing issues), is there
any tools or applications that actually generate files starting with
such encoding specific markers? Is there any issues arising from such
markers being present in files in such encodings maybe as a result of
conversion from other encodings. The practical implication of this: is
it a good practice to detect such markers by an application in the
pool of its supported encodings, if at least to ignore and skip them
to avert an error.

Comment: Does it really matter? Either your app can convert BOCU-1 to Unicode code points or it can't. If it can, you will find the BOM in the result (and don't need to know FB EE 28). If it can't, there's no point in knowing FB EE 28. You certainly can't skip them.

Comment: These BOMs are just plain cooky.  It's like Bill Bryson's remark about the difference between a language and a dialect: a language is a dialect with an army and a navy.  There is/was some kind of big company behind these BOM choices that got them registered somewhere.  Like IBM behind UTF-EBCDIC, the Chinese government behind GB-18030.  Practical usage is zilch, don't code for them unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: Safer to detect and skip them. It depends on you application, but imagine something like jsp, or asp, mustache, or any other kind of templating framework that puts together strings from various files. You can end up with "BOMs" in the middle of the final string, where they don't mean BOM anymore. Still safe, probably, but no guarantees ...